# Probability of number of faces with 2 and 5 equaling after 6 rolls of a dice

Tags: probability, dice

I have one dice and I roll it six times, recording the number I get each time. What is the probability that the number of 2s I get equals the number of 5s.

I try solve this using the trinomial distribution

$P(X_1 = x_1, X_2=x_2,X_3=3)=\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}p_3^{x_3} $ , or

$P(X_1 = x_1, X_2=x_2)=\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!(n-x_1-x_2)!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}(1-p_1-p_2)^{(n-x_1-x_2)}$

with $X_1 =$ number of faces equaling 2, $X_2 =$ number of faces equaling 5,

then we have to find

$P(X_1 = 1, X_2=1)+P(X_1 = 2, X_2=2)+P(X_1 = 3, X_2=3), n=6$

and

$P(X_1 = 1, X_2=1)=\frac{6!}{4!}*\frac{1}{6^2}(\frac{2}{3})^{4}=\frac{40}{243}, p_1=p_2=1/6$
$P(X_1 = 2, X_2=2)=\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}*\frac{2^22^2}{6^2*6^2}(\frac{1}{3})^{2}=\frac{10}{81}, p_1=p_2=2/6$
$P(X_1 = 3, X_2=3)=\frac{6!}{3!3!}*\frac{3^33^3}{6^3*6^3}=\frac{5}{16}, p_1=p_2=3/6$

so $P(X_1 = 1, X_2=1)+P(X_1 = 2, X_2=2)+P(X_1 = 3, X_2=3)=\frac{2335}{3888}=0.60057...$

Did I solve it right? A probability of about 60% seems a bit too big for this scenario. Is the problem with how I have defined my $p_1$ and $p_2$. I assumed that in this case it would be the proportion of which the event happens, so $\frac{1}{6}$ of the n faces shows a certain number.etc Other wise, I would think that still with $p_1=p_2$ but they are the probability that $x_1$ or $x_2$ faces of a dice are a certain number which then I would find with the binomial distribution.

Comment: You forgot the term $P(X_1=0=X_2)$.

Comment: @drhab, Arr yep, noted thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer looks too big because the calculations for $P(X_1=X_2=2,3)$ are wrong; $p_1,p_2$ remain at $\frac16$ for these cases.
$$P(X_1=X_2=2)=\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}(1/6)^2(1/6)^2(2/3)^2=5/162$$
$$P(X_1=X_2=3)=\frac{6!}{3!3!0!}(1/6)^3(1/6)^3(2/3)^0=5/11664$$
Then there is the case where no 2s and 5s are rolled, which is still an equal number of each:
$$P(X_1=X_2=0)=\frac{6!}{0!0!6!}(1/6)^0(1/6)^0(2/3)^6=\frac{64}{729}$$
Adding these up gives a final probability of around $0.2837$.

Comment: Om, but I am not sure why $p_{1,2}$ remain the same. Could you explain that a bit further. I thought It was like this where 'x' represents the other roll faces: (2) (x) (x) (x) (x) (x) or (x) (x) (5) (x) (x) (x) which is $\frac{1}{6}$ each and (2) (2) (x) (x) (x) (x) or (x) (x) (5) (x) (5) (x) which is $\frac{2}{6}$.

Comment: @glockm15 The probability of rolling a 2 (or 5) on any die remains $\frac16$ no matter how many dice there are. The multinomial distribution is probability for a fixed probability of the 2s/5s/others, but varying _counts_ of those events.

Comment: Got it , thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$P\left(X_{2}=X_{5}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{3}P\left(X_{2}=k=X_{5}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{3}\binom{6}{k,k,6-2k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{6-2k}=$$$$6^{-6}\sum_{k=0}^{3}\binom{6}{k,k,6-2k}4^{6-2k}$$

Check yourself.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what the combination part with "," means, I think I understand the rest

Comment: $\binom{n}{r,s,t}$ stands for $\frac{n!}{r!s!t!}$ if $r+s+t=n$ then it is a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: Got it thanks, new notation for me